# Chrome Extension insert style inline not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have tried to google but don't seem to be able to find an answer.

Im trying to make a Chrome extension that does 1 thing, changes/inserts style.display property to 1 or more elements. Normally this is trivial but for some reason I can not get it to work with an extension.

The *manifest.json* file

```
  {
    "name": "My app",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Do thing.",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/",
"tabs", "https://*/"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
            "js": ["myapp.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

and the *myapp.js*

```
document.getElementById("rightCol").style.display="none";
```

But its not doing anything.

Comment: 1) if you do the same thing manually in the chrome developer tool, do you get the required task? 2) after your extension run, check this #rightCol item in devtool, can you see display:none?

Comment: Did you use a mechanism in the content script in order for it to wait for the rest of the page to load (load event listener or `$(document).ready()`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the delay in coming back. It turns out its not the script, for some reason I had to restart chrome after EACH change.

after that it would not always hide the bars to which I fixed by adding this to the myapp.css

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", listener, false);
```

then the hiding in the listener function (inside a try/catch incase it wasn't on the screen).

Now works perfect and is even in the Chrome web store :) 
for anyone interested here is the link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-facebook-adsfacebook/pkconkhalmgfkbikgonhonmmlbkkoonc

Comment: You don't have to restart Chrome, it's enough to 1) reload the extension on the extensions page, 2) refresh the page so the new content script is injected.

Comment: thats what i originally thought and was doing but it didn't work till i restarted, now for updates it works to reload so weirdness

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the element is added programmatically by the page after `document_end` is fired. This can be solved, and the whole task simplified, if you inject CSS instead of a script.

This should accomplish what you're trying to do, *unless the page itself is overriding this rule programmatically*:

- In the manifest file change `content_scripts` as follows:

  ```
  "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
          "css": ["myapp.css"]
      }
  ]
  ```
- And use the following `myapp.css`:

  ```css
  #rightCol { 
      display:none !important;
  }
  ```

Comment: so this would override the existing css? I didn't know that was possible :)

Comment: @bensonsearch it depends, but in most cases yes. See [this overview](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) of CSS specificity. (`!important` + id) wins unless the page itself sets the style attribute with `!important`.